# When should transient object be used in interaction diagram?

Tags: uml

Here is the exercise I have to solve out.

Suppose that in a banking system a transfer is carried out in the following way: a transfer object is created to control the interaction, and the two accounts and the amount to be transferred are then passed as parameters to a 'doTransfer' method in the transfer object. Draw a collaboration diagram illustrating this interaction.

According to the book I am reading, if an object is created and destroyed in the course of a single interaction, it can be labelled on a collaboration diagram with the property "transient".
For this exercise, the transfer object should be transient object for each transfer process? Should transfer object be created for each transfer process?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the property "transient" is part of UML at all, but rather an invention of the author of the book you are reading.

I would advice against the use of such things unless it is defined in your companies modeling guidelines, and everyone involved knows what it means.

Typically a (data) transfer object (DTO) would indeed be created and destroyed for each transfer process.

Comment: See chapter 6.3.3 of Superstructures

Comment: @ThomasKilian I've read that, but there is still nowhere a property "transient" on any of the meta classes in UML.

Comment: 6.3.3. is about a conforming to some conditions, not about an additional kind of object. The UML specification does not define such thing as a transient object.

Comment: In the suggested answer for this exercise, creation and deletion of the transfer object is not included in the diagram. What if i use only one transfer object for every transfer process? Can i label transfer object as control object <<control>>?

Comment: I wasn't telling that 6.3.3 declares the "transient" property (it doesn't). Just wanted to link the appropriate reference.

Comment: @ThomasKilian ah, OK, I misunderstood you then.

Comment: @JuJu If you are talking about the Entity/Boundary/Control pattern I think your transfer object would rather be entity objects then control objects. But again, that is not strictly UML. Use these notations only if your organisations modeling guidelines describe them.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I am sorry  if my question is a very stupid question. But many things are very confusing in my mind. If transfer object is destroyed for each transfer process then if i want to know which account transfer how much to which object, which object should be used?